# How to add an input type text to CKEditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to make simple web editor using CKEditor but i cant find out how to make it work with input type text, It working well in textarea.

First i checked their samples site. Only thing they do to make CKEditor work is include .js file and add ckeditor class to form input type text element.

```
<script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
.
.
.
<input type="text" class="ckeditor" name="editor1" >
```

How I add ckeditor in input type = text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

with HTML like

```
<input type="text" class="ckeditor" name="editor1">
```

should just work, check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/f1ames/pen/qpjKxq). Maybe check for errors in the browser console or if the `ckeditor.js` file is loaded properly?